# Derivative of sum of powers (Apostol Exercise 4.6.38)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm self-studying Apostol's *Calculus* and I have some doubts about this exercise. The basic idea is as follows. We know that $1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ (for $x\not=1$, naturally). So, if $f(x)= 1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^n$, then $f'(x) = (\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1})' = \frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}$. That's the easy part of the exercise. However, he asks us to consider next the derivative of $1^2x + 2^2x^2 + 3^2x^3 + \dots + n^2x^n$, which I'm having some difficult in deriving---I think the approach I have taken may be a bit too cumbersome?

Here's what I thought. First, we can consider the following identities:

$$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^2x^i &= x\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^2x^{i-1} \\\\
&=x(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n ix^i)' \\\\
&=x(x\sum\limits_{i=0}^n ix^{i-1})' \\\\
&=x(x(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^i)')' \\\\
&=x(x(\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}))' \\\\
&=x(\frac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2})'
\end{align}$$

Hence, we have that:

$$\begin{align}(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^2x^i)' &= (x(\frac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2})')'\\\\
&= (\frac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2})' + x(\frac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2})''\end{align}$$

Unfortunately, calculating those last derivatives involves some really tedious algebraic manipulation, so I'd at least like to know that I'm on the right track before spending more time on this kind of work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have impression that the exercises are: find formulas for $ \sum_{i=1}^nix^i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2x^i$ applying the derivative.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc - Huh, you're right, I misread the exercise. That makes it easier, though that last derivative is still very tedious. Still, if you want to work it out and post that as an aswer, feel free.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you tried to simplify things too early. When it comes to derivatives, sums are much more preferable than products.

---

Let $f_i(x) = x^i$. Then, solving the first exercise is just $$\begin{align*}f(x) &= \sum_{i = 0}^n f_i(x) \\ \frac{d}{dx}f(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{i = 0}^n f_i(x)\right).\end{align*}$$

Recall that the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives. That is, $$\frac{d}{dx}\big[f(x) + g(x)\big] = \frac{d}{dx}f(x) + \frac{d}{dx}g(x).$$ This means that we can move the derivative operator inside the summation: $$\begin{align*}\frac{d}{dx}f(x) &= \sum_{i = 0}^n \left(\frac{d}{dx}f_i(x)\right)\end{align*}$$ Solving for $\frac{d}{dx}f_i(x)$,
$$\begin{align*}f_i(x) &= x^i \\ \frac{d}{dx}f_i(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}x_i \\ \frac{d}{dx}x_i &= ix^{i - 1}\end{align*}$$

This gives us $$\boxed{\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n ix^{i - 1}.}$$

---

You can do the same thing with the second exercise. Let $g_i(x) = i^2 x^i$. Then,
$$\begin{align*}g(x) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n g_i(x) \\ \frac{d}{dx}g(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n g_i(x)\right) \\ \frac{d}{dx}g(x) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \left(\frac{d}{dx}g_i(x)\right)\end{align*}$$

Solving for $\frac{d}{dx}g_i(x)$, $$\begin{align*}g_i(x) &= i^2x^i \\ \frac{d}{dx}g_i(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}(i^2x^i) \\ \frac{d}{dx}g_i(x) &= i^2 \cdot ix^{i - 1} \\ \frac{d}{dx}g_i(x) &= i^3 x^{i - 1}\end{align*}$$ Therefore, $$\boxed{\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n i^3x^{i - 1}.}$$